# Most basic config for PHP-FPM

Tags: php, fastcgi

I was reading [this article](https://www.shimmercat.com/en/docs/1.5/guides-php/) and they complain that PHP-FPM is difficult to configure.

I did some search on my own and I couldn't find any minimal examples of PHP-FPM configuration. Thus my question, is there an easy way to run PHP-FPM with just a one-liner command, without complicated configuration files?  Alt, what is the smallest configuration file I can use for a very basic website?